# Как отправлять http запросы с задержкой Promise<AxiosResponse>?

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, axios

Идея заключается в том, чтобы отправлять http запросы с определенной задержкой. Есть массив и в forEach делается отправка запроса. Но проблема  в том, что он выполняет запросы моментально.

```
const http: Promise<AxiosResponse>
```

Пытался сделать так:

```
function timer() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
}
```

И в каждой итерации массива вызывать так:

```
await timer();
```

Однако это не работает (почему?) и все итерации выполняются без задержки.
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Код:

```
function timer() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
}

projects.forEach(async project => {
await timer();
    const result = this.httpService.get(`${url}`, {auth}).toPromise();
    const projectProfile = await result.then(res => res.data);
```

Comment: Покажите полный, работающий пример кода, который бы воспроизводил ошибку.

Comment: Прошу прощения, добавил

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите отправлять каждый следующий запрос, по окончании предыдущего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравните два приведенных примера. Думаю, вы все сами поймете.

```js
function delay() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));
}

[0, 1, 2].forEach(async project => {
  console.log('before', project);
  await delay();
  console.log('after', project);
});
```

```js
function delay() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));
}

(async function() {
  for (let project = 0; project < 3; project++) {
    console.log('before', project);
    await delay();
    console.log('after', project);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Тогда уж `for (const project of [1, 2, 3])`

Comment: @PavelMayorov разницы особой нету, как делать цикл. Можно и `while`.

Comment: Разница в том, что в первом варианте у вас происходит обход массива, а во втором - просто счёт от 0 до 2х без, собственно, массива.

Comment: А цикл `for-of` - это прямая замена для метода `forEach`

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы думаете, это важное различие в контексте данного вопроса?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо! А что  обусловлено таким поведением?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я думаю, важно показать что код может быть очень просто переписан с метода `forEach` на цикл `for` без особых хитростей

Comment: @PavelMayorov я вас понял. Правда я не считаю, что классический цикл for можно назвать хитростью)))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko хитрость - не в цикле, а в том, что в классическом цикле обязательна отдельная переменная для массива, а доступ через переменную заменяется на доступ по индексу

Comment: @PavelMayorov это хитрость? Это важно в контексте данного вопроса?